# How to subscibe to observables data in angularjs2

Tags: angular, typescript

I had an edit button through which i pass a student id and on click i display the student details in a form but the the problem is i had observables there and i got strucked there.Cn someone please help me....

My template tag,

```
 <form  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"  >
   First name:<br>
      <input    [formControl]="form.controls['name']" [(ngModel)]="details.name"  type="text" name="firstname">
          <br>
     Age:<br>
  <input    [formControl]="form.controls['age']" [(ngModel)]="details.age"   type="text" name="age">
     <button  type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
```

My Ts,

```
    edit(id): any {
    //console.log(id);
    this.property = 'update';
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    this.http.get('http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/editprofiledb/' + id, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(response => {
            if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
                this.details = <IStudent2[]>response.json().data;

            } else {
                this.details = <IStudent2[]>response.json().data;
             }

            })
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I am not getting the data to my form .....so far i used these code in another ts and subscribed to it in main.ts but now i dont have clue how to write it in main.ts

Comment: I can't see how this is related to `main.ts` or how this is related to a form.

Comment: i will post the code

Comment: actually the above is in main.ts only

Comment: edited my code.............

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. I don't see anything obviously wrong. What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: oHH thats my mistake,any way Thank you Gunter